# How can i display pdf file in my ASP.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I want to click my linkbutton and open my pdf file that project has.
How can i do this?

in aspx page:

in cs page:
private void pdfShow_Click(){

///Please help this.
}

Comment: Where do you store the PDF - file system or database?

Answer (score 0):

try this it's simpler
Response.Clear();

```
string filePath = ur file path on the server like ~/123.pdf

Response.contentType = "application/pdf";

Response.WriteFile(filePath);
```

Comment: please provide some clarification of your answer

Comment: @Wais Please edit your existing [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37191392/296861) instead of creating a new one.

Comment: what's the path to your pdf file something like ~/123.pdf